# Twitter Bootstrap mobile only columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to make 'mobile only' columns in Boostrap? i.e. a row of 4 becoming a row of 2 on smaller screens (3 * span4s becoming 2 * span6?). I know you can hide elements for mobile by adding `.hidden-phone`.

Zurb Foundation has `phone-two` etc classes which do this. http://www.zurb.com/article/859/fancy-mobile-layouts-with-the-foundation-

Will I need to write my own media queries to do this?

Comment: Media Queries won't really help you here as you're talking about changing the HTML rather than simply changing HTML styles via CSS. You could use Bootstraps 'hidden' classes that you've mentioned above to hide some content on larger devices and display it on smaller devices but this means both sets of content will be downloaded then shown or hidden.

Comment: the thing is foundation has 'phone-two' and I was wondering if bootstrap had anything similar: http://www.zurb.com/article/859/fancy-mobile-layouts-with-the-foundation-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap does not have the built-in equivalent of the classes you are asking about.

Here's an idea to get you started if you want to write your own: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/g6PRS/

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-fluid.phone-two .span3 {
    width: 48%;
    margin-left: 4%;
    float:left;
  }

  .row-fluid.phone-two > .span3:nth-child(odd){
    margin-left: 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row-fluid phone-two">
    <div class="span3">
      span3
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      span3
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      phone-two span3
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      span3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this is enought to get you going!

Answer (score 1):

Quick update bootstrap 3 now supports what you wanted to do here.

e.g

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-6'>
   </div>

   <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-6'>
   </div>

   <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-6'>
   </div>

   <div class='col-xs-3 col-md-6'>
   </div>
</div>
```

Havent tested this but should work. Should show 2 columns on mobile and 4 columns on desktop. More information http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid